# TimeSeriesShift issue with TimeZone

Tags: bugs, date-and-time, time-series

I have to work with such a TimeZone to deal with daylight saving time.

```
$TimeZone = "Europe/Paris";
td = TimeSeries[Range@10,{Table[Now-Quantity[1,"Days"]*i,{i,Range@10}]}]
TimeSeriesShift[td, Quantity[1, "Hours"]]
```

Last line leads to the following error :
"Time zone specification ("Europe/Paris") should be a real number, integer, or time zone string."

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug. You could work with `Entity` time zone specification for the time being:

```
td = TimeSeries[
   Range@10, 
   {Table[Now - Quantity[1, "Days"]*i, {i, Range@10}]}
];

TimeSeriesShift[
  td, Quantity[1, "Hours"], TimeZone -> Entity["TimeZone", "Europe/Paris"]
] // Normal
```

> {{Sun 23 Dec 2018 22:53:27CET,10},{Mon 24 Dec 2018 22:53:27CET,9},{Tue 25 Dec 2018 22:53:27CET,8},{Wed 26 Dec 2018 22:53:27CET,7},{Thu 27 Dec 2018 22:53:27CET,6},{Fri 28 Dec 2018 22:53:27CET,5},{Sat 29 Dec 2018 22:53:27CET,4},{Sun 30 Dec 2018 22:53:27CET,3},{Mon 31 Dec 2018 22:53:27CET,2},{Tue 1 Jan 2019 22:53:27CET,1}}